# Location of parser index/cache for c++ in Netbeans 7.3+ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, caching, netbeans

Where can i find the the parser index/cache for a specific c++ project in netbeans 7.3+?

I used grep to look up some function names i used in this project.

```
grep -nisr ~/<netbeansfolder> '<function name here>'
grep -nisr ~/.neatbeans/<version> '<function name here>'
grep -nisr ~/<projectfolder>/nbproject '<function name here>'
```

Found nothing... any clues or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
~/.cache/netbeans/<netbeansversion>/cnd/model/
```